# #DIV/0! error with AVERAGEIFS formula. How to convert to '0'?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with the below formula. Each time when there is no data available for specific day, I have the #DIV/0! error.

My formula is as follows:

```
 =IF(B$14<=MAX('BI Raw Data'!$B:$B),AVERAGEIFS('BI Raw Data'!$Z:$Z,'BI Raw Data'!$AM:$AM,"Yes",'BI Raw Data'!$B:$B,'CC - TABLES'!B$14),)
```

I tried to get rid of this error with the IFFERROR function but without success:

```
=IFERROR(B$14<=MAX('BI Raw Data'!$B:$B),AVERAGEIFS('BI Raw Data'!$Z:$Z,'BI Raw Data'!$AM:$AM,"Yes",'BI Raw Data'!$B:$B,'CC - TABLES'!B$14),0)
```

or

```
=IFERROR(B$14<=MAX('BI Raw Data'!$B:$B),AVERAGEIFS('BI Raw Data'!$Z:$Z,'BI Raw Data'!$AM:$AM,"Yes",'BI Raw Data'!$B:$B,'CC - TABLES'!B$14),"0")
```

Can you please advise how to rectify this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting the error because there's no occurrence of "Yes" in column `AM` or the value in `B14` doesn't appear in column `B`.  Moving the `IFERROR` as @Scott suggests is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the IFERROR around the AVERAGE:

```
=IF(B$14<=MAX('BI Raw Data'!$B:$B),IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('BI Raw Data'!$Z:$Z,'BI Raw Data'!$AM:$AM,"Yes",'BI Raw Data'!$B:$B,'CC - TABLES'!B$14),0),)
```